# ошибка I\O Error 104 delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

как исправить ошибку  I\O Error 104
вот код

```
    procedure TForm1.sButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  f1, f2: TextFile;
  s1, s2: string;
  p: integer;
  filename1, filename2:string;
begin
  sMemo1.clear;
  FileName1 := 'bigFile.txt';
  FileName2 := 'littleFile.txt';
  AssignFile(f1, FileName1);
  Reset(f1);
  AssignFile(f2, FileName1);
  Reset(f2);
  while not Eof(f1) do
  begin
    readLn(f1,s1);
    CloseFile(f2);
    while not EOF(f2) do
    begin
      readLn(f2,s2);
      p := pos(s2, s1);
if (p > 0) then
begin
sMemo1.Lines.Add(S2);
sLabel1.Caption := IntToStr(sMemo1.Lines.Count);
sButton2.Enabled:=True;
end;
    end;
  end;
  CloseFile(f1);
  CloseFile(f2);

end;
```

Comment: `//CloseFile(f2);`

Answer (score 1):

У вас лишняя строка в середине кода - `CloseFile(f2);`.